# How would I store passwords in CouchDB using CouchRest & BCrypt?

Tags: ruby, security, couchdb, password-storage

Although, this isn't CouchDB specific, the library I'm using *is*. I'm using [couchrest_model](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model) in Ruby to create a `User` model like this below:

```
class User < CouchRest::Model::Base
  use_database 'sample'
  property :_id, String
  property :email, String
  # property :password
  timestamps!
end
```

I'm confused with password storing here. I'd like to use BCrypt but when I do something like this:

```
class User < CouchRest::Model::Base
  include BCrypt

  use_database 'sample'
  property :_id, String
  property :email, String
  property :password, BCryptHash

  timestamps!
end
```

I get told that `User::BCryptHash` is an uninitialised constant. I of course require the `bcrypt` library beforehand. Could you help me resolve that BCrypt issue or suggest a different way of storing passwords in CouchDB? I've looked at [hashing passwords](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html#hashing) however I'm not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'couchrest_model'

class User < CouchRest::Model::Base
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

  use_database 'sample'
  has_secure_password

  property :username, String
  property :email, String
  property :password_digest, String

  timestamps!

  design { view :by_email }
end

User.create(:username => 'rafalchmiel', :email => 'hi@rafalchmiel.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')
User.create(:username => 'bar', :email => 'hi@bar.com', :password => 'password213', :password_confirmation => 'password213')
User.create(:username => 'foo', :email => 'hi@foo.com', :password => 'password12111', :password_confirmation => 'password12111')
```

More info as to why this works in [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model/issues/177).